# Inserting date on just weekday pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I  have managed to take one day off in the query  but I would like it to step back onto weekdays only

EDIT :o)

This is my query

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(email, name, dob, reminder reminder1, reminder2, reminder3) VALUES (:email, :name, :dob  IF (WEEKDAY(:reminder) > 4, DATE_SUB(:reminder1, INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(:reminder2) - 4) DAY),:reminder3))");
        $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("dob", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("reminder", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("reminder1", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("reminder2", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("reminder3", $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
```

The form is giving me the OK the data has been added but nothing is getting added to the DB no errors

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for a very basic solution would be to use the [`WEEKDAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function in concert with the MySQL [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function.

The former will give you the index of the given date in the week in which it occurs (0 is Monday).  The latter provides the familiar service of the ternary operator you may have seen in other programming languages.

```
$query = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO users
    VALUES (
        :email, :name, :dob,
        IF (
          WEEKDAY(:reminder0) > 4,
          DATE_SUB(:reminder1, INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(:reminder2) - 4) DAY),
          :reminder3
        )
    )
');
```

You have to use unique named placeholders (see the documentation for [`prepare()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)).  Just bind the same date to `:reminder0` ... `:reminder3`.  An example execution would be as follows:

```
$query->execute([
    ':email' => 'example@example.org',
    ':name' => 'Example',
    ':dob' => '1970-01-01',
    ':reminder0' => '2018-12-12',
    ':reminder1' => '2018-12-12',
    ':reminder2' => '2018-12-12',
    ':reminder3' => '2018-12-12'
]);
```

It seems like, at this point, it would be easier to just perform the date calculation for `:reminder` with some PHP code in a function that wraps your original prepared statement. It's your call.

You should also bear in mind that this won't take into account holidays.  Your use case will dictate whether or not that fact is important.

Comment: Thanks, that returns an error but to be honest I do not understand what you said here "You have to use unique named placeholders (see the documentation for prepare()). Just bind the same date to :reminder0 ... :reminder3" can you make this clearer for me please..thank you

Comment: I mean this: you only have one date for the `:reminder` field.  However,  the same date must appear in multiple places throughout the query.  You can't use `:reminder` as a field name in more than one place.  Thus, you have to create 4 different place holders and bind the same date to them all.  See my updated answer for a example execution.  It shouldn't return an error... I tested it on my own PHP + MySQL installation.

Comment: Post edit: I have used the code as requested no errors just not going into the DB

Comment: I'm not having any trouble... I can see from your updated query that you don't really understand how PDO prepared statements work at a very basic level.  I suggest [this tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).  Best of luck.

Comment: No you are right I do not know what the statement should look like, I am still in learning mode as you can see, After reading the link you have shown me it is still as clear as mud as I learn from doing not reading, if I am shown the right way for a particular then I am a much better learner, when some tells me things like, this needs to go there and this is too much and do it this way I learn better, but thanks for your help